# How can I deploy my golang appliation developed on X86_64 architecture to server machine based on ARM64 architecture

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ec2, x86-64, arm64

My application is developed in Golang. My development hardware architecture is `X86_64` which is AMD compatible but my servers are based on `ARM_64` architecture. OS is *Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04*

Here is my development process

- Build app -> test -> build docker image -> push to Dockerhub.

Deployment process

- Docker-Compose file pulls the docker image and deploys to the Swarm cluster (ARM64)

Server machines are `EC2 t4large Standard Reserved Instances` and they are reserved for 3 years and I am not sure that I will be able to change this because they are reserved now.

How can I deploy my Golang app to my servers without any issues ??
Can I run my code build using `X86_64` architecture on `ARM64` ??

Comment: You can cross compile for ARM64 `GOARCH=arm64 go build`, this should then work on the container on EC2 there is an entire tutorial on it here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: one caveat - if you are using cgo, then you will need the right toolchain for the target platform. So it might be easier building it in the cloud on the target arch.

Comment: Thanks @Christian. I found another tutorial which is written in 2021 https://opensource.com/article/21/1/go-cross-compiling.

Comment: One of the possible solution would be to create docker image with `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o <executable_name> .` and push to Dockerhub. Deploy this image to the ARM64 docker swarm server. Is this correct approach ?

Comment: Do you need cgo enabled? And in theory this should all work, I would just try it and see if it works

Comment: `CGO_ENABLED` is written in the docker file. I just copied the command. Will this cause any problem?